# How to pass parameters between rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to pass parameters between two rails apps. In one side (sender) I have an array of hashes. I have a code like the following to send the data:

```
   http = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', '3030')
   result = http.post('/processar_lotes', my_array_of_hashes)
```

Some questions

- Is there any (kind of) serialize or something like this that I can pass to the other app?
- At the other side, how can I de-serialize the information?
- Is there a limit to the size of what I pass as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- There are many ways to 'serialize' the data. You can use your own custom format, or use a standard one. For example, you can try to use the Rails `to_xml` method, or the `to_json` method. You can also use Ruby's [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) object.
- Depending on your choice, this might be `from_json`, `from_xml`, `Marshal.load`, or your own custom reader.
- Normally, this is unlimited for HTTP posts, but depending on your server configuration, it could be less.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but I'd use XML. This would make your application much more flexible than using language-specific serialization.

It shouldn't be too hard to convert the array to XML and back.

**EDIT:** You might wanna check out [ROXML](http://roxml.rubyforge.org/) and [XML::Mapping](http://xml-mapping.rubyforge.org/).