# What are the options for passing parameters between two Rails 3 apps with a shared session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, parameters, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain

We have two Rails 3 apps that share a session via subdomains:

app1.domain.ca

app2.domain.ca

Just wondering what our options are for passing parameters between these apps, other than via the URI (we don't want to expose the app models to the users).

The only relevant thread I could find on here is from 2008; not sure whether these answers are still valid, or whether things have evolved since:

[How to pass parameters between rails applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270125/how-to-pass-parameters-between-rails-applications)

The options that come to mind are:

- To use the shared session
- Or, possibly, the options outlined in the post above (XML, JSON, Marshal)

Any others I'm missing? Or are there any leading practices for this at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your session store to work across multiple domains.

In config/initializers/session_store.rb :

```
RailsApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_rails_app_session', domain: :all
```

Comment: Thanks dms193; we already have the sessions shared though, and all of our apps will be on subdomains for the same domain.

Our issue is how to share parameters easily between these apps, without exposing our apps' models by passing the parameters via URIs.